# How to enable browser validation/disable novalidate with simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form, simple-form-for

How do I enable browser validation with the simple form gem for Rails? The `novalidate` attribute is set on my forms now that I use simple form.

Answer (score 2):

In the initializer simple_form.rb which the gem generated for you, set `config.browser_validations` to `true`.